# Does a 'copy' on Memory Mapped file trigger flush to disk?

Tags: linux, windows, memory-mapped-files

I have a memory mapped file opened in my Java program and I keep on writing new data into it.

Generally, the OS takes care of flushing the contents to the disk.

If for some reason, some other process wants to copy the file to another location (possibly do an `rsync`), then do I get the latest contents of that file (i.e. the contents that are there at that instant of time in the memory map?)

Typically, I feel that if a ***copy*** on a file that is memory mapped by a process is triggered, either of these 2 should happen

1. The contents of the file should be flushed to disk, so that other process sees that *latest* content of the file.
2. When a copy is triggered, it is generally copied to memory (when we are doing something like *rsync*) and then the contents will be written to the destination file from the memory. So, if they are to be copied from the memory, then the *pages* of the file are *already* in memory, since the other process is using it (memory mapped), so this page will be accessed and there is no need to flush to disk.

What happens exactly? Is it something other than the above mentioned?
Is it same behavior for both Windows and Linux?